# how to print tag image in html for html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html2canvas

```
html2canvas($('#head'), {
    allowTaint: true,
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var base64image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        console.log(base64image);

    }
});
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/h3p1ua74)

Comment: This question could do with additional context.  You mentioned that you don't see an image tag in your DOM, correct?  Do you see any errors in your JS console?  Any failed network requests?

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
html2canvas($('#head'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var base64image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        var tWindow = window.open("");
        $(tWindow.document.body)
            .html("<img id='Image' src=" + base64image + " style='width:100%;'></img>")
            .ready(function() {
                tWindow.focus();
                tWindow.print();
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it but it did not work. The picture does not show.